# Combining dataframe columns with similar entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following two dataframes that I am struggling to combine.

```
import re
import pandas as pd


wins=pd.DataFrame([{'Team':'Chicago Thunder Bolts', 'Wins':10},{'Team':'New York Tuskers', 'Wins': 15},{'Team':'Philly Steaks','Wins':25} ])
wins

losses=pd.DataFrame([{'Team':'Tuskers', 'Losses': 5},{'Team':'Steaks','Losses':2},{'Team':'Thunder Bolts', 'Losses':11} ])
```

I want to merge these two dataframes.

[image]

[image]

I want to combine the two frames and get something in the form

[image]

However, in the first date frame, the name of the team is preceded by the name of the city. Is there someway I can remove the name of the cities? If that can be done, then merging can be done very easily. Thank you!

Edit: Would prefer a method that avoids doing this manually. Especially if the number of rows are large.

Comment: How many rows do you have? Is it feasible to do it manually?

Comment: @flyingdutchman too many to do this manually

Comment: Would it work if you strip all the names to the last word, so e.g. Bolts and Tuskers?

Comment: @flyingdutchman good idea but there are some teams with the same last name

Comment: @Heisenberg: Did this help you? Do not forget to vote/accept answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following could do that, if the number of cities is not too large.

```
wins['Team'].replace(['New York', 'Chicago', 'Philly'], '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```